# Firebase for A/B testing with remote config

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

I need to run A/B testing and I was thinking about using Firebase remote config. I could not find whether it is possible to updated the app keeping the value for the A/B config between versions. What I mean is that if I publish the app and I target 20% of the user with a new feature and then I need to make an hotfix, would I be able to publish a new version without breaking the A/B test I mean leaving the user that had got the new feature with the same config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing a new version of the app will not change the way users are assigned into one of the groups created by Remote Config.

Comment: In Firebase, the random percentile condition (X% of users) is described as "A fractional percentile randomly and persistently assigned to each user on a per project basis". Crucially, 'persistently assigned'.